# Independent coordinates of a gaussian vector

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $(X^{(1)}, \ldots, X^{(n)})$ be a gaussian random vector. For $i\neq j$, Prove  that $X^{(i)}$ and $X^{(j)}$ are independent 
>   $\iff \text{Cov}(X^{(i)},X^{(j)})=0$.

I'm trying to work with the marginal distributions of $X^{(i)}$ and $X^{(j)}$ to conclude that the joint distribution $\rho_{X^{(i)},X^{(j)}}$ equals the product of the marginals, but the calculations are looking really complicated, so I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you have so far?  It is hard to see how you are stuck if we can't see where you are.

Comment: I tried to use brutal force, which means trying to integrate the density function with respect to all coordinates except $i $ and $j$, so that I find the joint distribution. But the density is very complicated since it envolves the inverse of the covariance matrix, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: One direction is trivial: if two random variables have finite variances their covariance exists, and if in addition they are independent then their covariance is $0$.  The other is considerably deeper. $\qquad$

Comment: I'm rusty on this, but I find a theorem says two random variables $X,Y$ are independent if for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ we have $\operatorname{E}(\exp(aX + bY)) = \operatorname{E}(\exp(aX)) \cdot \operatorname{E}(\exp(bY))$.  The same statement with "only if" is trivial.  This plus the fact that each one-dimensional normal distribution is determined by its expectation and variance, and that all moments are determined by the function $a\mapsto \operatorname{E}(\exp(aX))$, will do it. $\qquad$

Comment: I am rusty on this too, but here is a try: using the fact that any pair from the vector also follows a bivariate normal (this is an important fact that any affine transformation of multivariate normal is still multivariate normal; not sure if you can directly use this), then you only need to deal with the bivariate case. And for the bivariate case, if $\rho = 0$, then the covariance matrix is diagonal and you can split the quadratic form inside the exponential, and thus factorizing the joint pdf as the product of marginal.